# Getting Parameters from a Constructor

Tags: c#

I am trying to add the assigned parameters of a constructor to a list inside a list.

```
public class assignCells
  {
    List<List<Vector3>> Cells = new 
    List<List<Vector3>>();
 public assignCells(Vector3 bottom, Vector3 top, Vector3 right, Vector3 left)
 {
     Type Parm = typeof(assignCells);
     Type[] VC = new Type[3];
     VC[0] = typeof(Vector3);
     VC[1] = typeof(Vector3);
     VC[2] = typeof(Vector3);
     VC[3] = typeof(Vector3);
     ConstructorInfo Constructbase = Parm.GetConstructor(VC);
     if (top.x == bottom.x + 20.0 && 
        right.x == left.x + 50.0)
     {
         Cells.Add(Constructbase.GetParameters());
     }
 }
}
```

This code, however, does not work. The last line just says it can't convert from parameter info to a list of vectors. I would really appreciate any help, even if you have to tell me that I am going about it in the completely wrong way.

Comment: You should be getting an index out of bounds error because you initialize `VC` to a size of 3, but attempt to put a 4th item in it.

Comment: What are you _actually_ trying to achieve?

Comment: Why not just `Cells.Add(new List<Vector3>{bottom, top, right, left});`?

Comment: `new[] { bottom, top, right, left }` is an array containing exactly the parameters. Unlike (say) scripting languages, C# has no (efficient, usable) mechanism for reflecting over the actual arguments of a function dynamically -- fortunately, that's not exactly needed either, beyond perhaps saving some keystrokes. Note that if you often find `bottom`, `top`, `right` and `left` together, that's usually an indication that some compound type is struggling to get out, which could be passed as a single parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following :

```
   public class assignCells
    {
        List<List<Vector3>> Cells = new List<List<Vector3>>();
        public assignCells(Vector3 bottom, Vector3 top, Vector3 right, Vector3 left)
        {

            List<Vector3> newListVector3 = new List<Vector3>() { bottom, top, right, left };
            Cells.Add(newListVector3);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understood quite mch your model but i suggest you to try this code

```
public class AssignCells
    {
        List<List<ParameterInfo>> Cells = new List<List<ParameterInfo>>();
        public AssignCells(Vector3 bottom, Vector3 top, Vector3 right, Vector3 left)
        {
            Type Parm = typeof(AssignCells);
            Type[] VC = new Type[4];
            VC[0] = typeof(Vector3);
            VC[1] = typeof(Vector3);
            VC[2] = typeof(Vector3);
            VC[3] = typeof(Vector3);
            var Constructbase = Parm.GetConstructor(VC);
            if (top.x == bottom.x + 20.0 && right.x == left.x + 50.0)
            {
                Cells.Add(Constructbase.GetParameters().ToList());
            }
        }
    }
```

`Cells` should be list of list of `ParameterInfo` to avoid compilation error. and the `.ToList()` comes here to allow conversion from `Array` to `List`
Hope that helps !